# How to fix python module not found error with jenkins?

Tags: python, jenkins

I ran pip freeze command with my jenkins job and below is the output

```
pip freeze 
fpdf==1.7.2
textfile==0.1.4

pip install textfile 
Requirement already satisfied: textfile in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (0.1.4)
```

But when I ran the python script as a job, getting error as below.

```
 $ python C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins2938633000292670144.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins2938633000292670144.py", line 1, in <module>
    import textile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textile'
Build step 'Execute Python script' marked build as failure
No emails were triggered.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> pip install text*f*ile 
> Requirement already satisfied: textfile in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (0.1.4)
> ```

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'text*i*le'
> ```

It's not complaining that [text***f***ile](https://pypi.org/project/textfile/) is not found; it's complaining that [textile](https://pypi.org/project/textile/) is not found.

Install `textile` and try again.

Comment: my bad.. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. We all make similar silly mistakes :) I'd recommend a [rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) for first instance debugging. The best thing is that they have a very strict code of secrecy with regards to what you tell them :)